# Elasticsearch is not parsing hours time correctly

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is not parsing time correctly, it detects the date correctly but is not parsing hours correctly.

**Index mapping**

```
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "send_date": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}            
        }
  }
```

**Python date**

```
df_date = "2020-05-04 12:08:04"
```

**Elasticsearch is parsing this**

```
May 4, 2020 @ 14:08:04.000
```

In this case everything is correct but hours

Comment: Are you copying that date from Kibana? If yes, then I think you're in the GMT+2 timezone, right ?

Comment: Hello @val i am inserting dates from python elasticsearch package .bulk. Yes, i am looking the date in Kibana discover. How can i fix that?

Comment: I would need to mantain the exact time that i have in python dataframes

Comment: Fixed, kibana management. dateFormat:tz to UTC

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, with @Val help.

Just change Kibana setting to UTC.

Management -> Advance Settings -> Timezone for date formating